# Vue.js style working on wrong element

Tags: javascript, dom, vue.js

It's really strange. 
I'm making floating sidebar in the Vue component, so need to change the css position value between fixed and relative. 
so what I did is giving an ID for the sidebar element, and on scroll event, check the position on the page and changed some css values.

Here is my code.

```
created() {
    document.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
},
destroyed() {
    document.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
}
/* ... */ 
handleScroll(e) {
  var doc = document.documentElement;
  var top = (window.pageYOffset || doc.scrollTop) - (doc.clientTop || 0);
  var originWidth = $("#fields-to-move").width() + 2;
  if(this.screen_no == 2){
    if (280 <= top) {
      document.getElementById("fields-to-move").style.position = "fixed";
      document.getElementById("fields-to-move").style.top = 10 + 'px' ;
      document.getElementById("fields-to-move").style.width = originWidth + 'px'; 
    } else {
      document.getElementById("fields-to-move").style.position = "relative"; 
      document.getElementById("fields-to-move").style.top = 'auto' ;
      document.getElementById("fields-to-move").style.width = originWidth + 'px'; 
     }
 }
}
```

"fields-to-move" is the ID of DOM element I'm going to change css. 
It's working well.

But the problem is that above css ( position: fixed, top:10px and width) also applied on other element without the ID.

There's one thing more need to mention. 
The element with the ID is a child element of another one which is mounted with v-if condition. 
After the parent element dismounted, the css is applied to the wrong element that's mounted after it.

I'm not sure my explanation is enough. Please let me know if you have any questions above my problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you can provide separeted example in jsfiddle it would be easier to help...
But I belive that this behaviour can caused by some Vue optimizations described here: [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#Controlling-Reusable-Elements-with-key)

edit:
Try to execute entire logic of "handleScroll" in vues nextTick.